# Media queries not working in Bootstrap with some classes, but with others it does

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have media queries, but for some reason for one particular class doesn't works. I'm using Bootstrap modals for this. I would need this to work best at 420 width.

Here is my CSS code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .caracs{
    width: 500px !important;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    } 
    .panel{
    text-align: center;
    height: 255px;
    }
    .nombre-datos{
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .caracs{
        width: 810px !important;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .nombre-datos{
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .caracs{
    width: 810px !important;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .panel{
        text-align: center;
        height: 165px;
    }
}
```

Specifically I need:

```
.nombre-datos{
    display: inline-block; /*Necesario para que los divs estén en el mismo renglón*/
    width: 250px !important;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

To change. I want to remove the *width: 250px !important* property on small screens, tho when I resize the window in my browser it doesn't works at all.

Here are some pics:

This is how it looks on normal screen view:

[image]

Here is how it looks responsive to small devices:

[image]

Here it is how I want it to look, removing the specified property (I'm using Firefox inspector/dev tools to remove it):

[image]

What is happening?

Comment: remove  !important then define in media query

Comment: @HeadInCloud You mean remove it from the class **outside** the query? Or both? If you mean outside, I already did it and still doesn't works.

Comment: Have you tried editing the css within the browser dev tools to see if it works that way?

Comment: @kemosabe Yep, in fact that's what I'm showing in the last picture.

Comment: The only thing I can venture to guess at the moment is like @Head in Cloud was saying you've got that same element set to 250px !important somewhere else and it's overriding the media query. I don't think there is any way to override !important unless you state another !important within the media qurey. For example, put in your media query that you want the width to be 500px !important and that might do what you need.

Comment: @kemosabe I found that changing *min-width* to *max-width* makes it, tho it ruins other CSS styling. Does that means I should redesign the specifications? Or just need to add code inside that new media query to solve those problems?

Comment: @dawn if it were me, I would just fix what needs to be fixed within the media query that it's broken in. No need to go to the main css and mess up all the styles that have been set for other media sizes.

Comment: @kemosabe Okai, I solved it. You can take a look at the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okai, I'm not completely sure what's happening but doing this:

Meaning, changed a query from *min* to *max* and forcing with *!important* some stuff did the trick **without** messing anything else.

```
 @media (max-width: 992px) { 
    .caracs{
        /*width: 810px !important;*/
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .nombre-datos{
        width: 364px !important;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        text-align: justify;
    }
}
```